# How to render specific pages (not entire PDF file) using react-pdf-viewer?

Tags: reactjs, pdf-viewer, react-pdf-viewer

I am working on a React project for displaying pdf files using React. My website has a feature for user to open a PDF file and display only pages that they want.

For example: If the user input: 1, 4, 7, 9, 10. The PDF file will only render these pages while hidding other pages.

Is there a way to do this using react-pdf-viewer or we need to use another library for this?

I have tried different pdf libraries but they do not have the option to display the specific pages. All of them are displaying the entire PDF file.